# Cordova does not "see" Android SDK version

Tags: android, cordova

I am in the process of setting up a new Cordova CLI toolchain to build hybrid Android apps that target Android 5.1+.  I am using

- Node 8.9.2
- Cordova 7.1.0

After issuing a `cordova create...` command to create a new Cordova project I proceeded to add Android 5.1 using `cordova platform add android@5.1.0` which went smoothly.

I have also ensured that I have the relevant Android SDKs available and pointed at properly via `ANDROID_HOME`.  I currently have SDKs 19 through to 27 installed.

However, when I issue a `cordova build android` I get the message `Error: Android SDK not found`.  Strangely enough if I let Cordova install its current default Android version via `cordova platform add android` which adds Android 6.3.1 it then lets me build the project without any further ado.

Is this a matter of Cordova 7.1.0 simply not wanting to play ball with lower versions of Android or is there something else going on here?  Can I get around this by installing an older version of Cordova via npm?  If so, which version should I install - and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're adding an old version of the [cordova-android](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android) platform project, ([v5.1.0](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/tree/rel/5.1.0)) which is over 2 years old and not compatible with the `cordova@7.1.0` CLI.

If you want to target Android 5.1+, you don't need to use `cordova-android@5.1.0`, you need to specify a [preference in the `config.xml`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#preference) to target [Android 5.1 (API 22)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#api-level-table) and above:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
```

You probably want to use the default `cordova-android` platform version (6.3.1), unless you need to do stuff with Android Studio 3, in which case use `cordova platform add android@latest` which will add `cordova-android@7.0.0` and requires Gradle 4 to build ([see here](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html)).